Can I add a light control sensor to my 2012 Toyota Corolla?
I have a 2012 Toyota Corolla that doesn't have a sensor to turn the headlights on automatically when it gets dark. I found that the option for this is part #89121-12010.
When I look at YouTube videos for people adding these kinds of light sensors to their vehicle, I see them prying up a dummy cap with a cable attached to it. On my car, however, it looks like the cap is part of the injection molding. Even if I were to clip it out with some side cutters, I'm not confident that the cable harness exists underneath.
Is it possible to add this sensor to my car or do I need the cable harness as well and someone experienced enough to hook it up to the electrical system.
I recently upgraded from a 2002 to a 2012 Corolla, and I'm having trouble adjusting to not having the automatic headlight sensor and the headlight door alarm; neither of which exist on my new car.

